# Sum of series where exponent is sum of arithmetic progression

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progression

How do I get the sum of such a sequence:

$$1 + x^{-1} + x^{-3} + x^{-6} + \dotsb,$$

where the exponents are actually sum of arithmetic progression? I.e.,

$$x^{-0} + x^{-(0 + 1)} + x^{-(0 + 1 + 2)} + x^{-(0 + 1 + 2 + 3)} + \dotsb,$$

which can also be expressed as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{-\frac{i(i + 1)}{2}}.$$

Comment: Mathematica says: $\frac{1}{2} x^{1/8} \big( \frac{2}{x^{1/8}} + \text{EllipticTheta}\big[2, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\big]\big)$.

Comment: If there exists a formula (which sounds unlikely) for that one,  then it could be modified to work for any arithmetic progression since it would just be a linear translation of the exponent, which would mean applying the function to $x^b$ and multiplying by $x^a$.

Now, is there a closed-form formula? I doubt it.

Comment: oh wait that's not true sorry.

Comment: I would bet that the function is not elementary but it'll take some effort to prove it. Are you really curious about this stuff or it is just a random question?

Comment: i was solving a markov process equation when i ended up with such a series. from the looks of the complexity, it is much more possible that i got something wrong somewhere and ended up like that... (unfortunately i still couldn't figure out what went wrong...)

Comment: what markov chain gave you a theta function as solution??

Answer (score 6):

I think you can get it from the [Jacobi triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)
\[ \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-x^{2m})(1-x^{2m-1}y^2)(1+x^{2m-1}y^{-2}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2}y^{2n}  \]
We can set $x = q^{1/2}, y = q^{1/2}$.
\[ \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-q^{m})(1-q^{m+\frac{1}{2}})(1+q^{m-\frac{3}{2}}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \]
This is close to what you want.

Triple product identity and the theory of partition is [still actively studied](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=triple+product+identity&terms-0-field=all&classification-mathematics=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first) in many contexts.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and make a guess that expressing the infinite sum as an infinite product is not what OP wanted (but is as good as OP is going to get). 

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobi Theta function $\text{JacobiTheta2}(z,q)$ (in Maple's notation) is
$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }2 \cos \left(\left( 2k+1 \right) z  \right) {
q}^{\left( 2 k+1 \right) ^{2}/4}$.  So what you have is $\text{JacobiTheta2}(0,\sqrt{1/x}) x^{1/8}/2 $ (for $|x| >1$).